# iCloud mail attachment limit size

Tags: icloud, email-attachments

Does anyone know the iCloud mail attachment limit size?
Because I have mail delivery failure sometimes when I send with an attachment over 10 Mo.

Comment: according to this post I found on google they say 20mb - [link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1220673)

Answer (score 1):

2 MB is the limit for i cloud e mail attachment. 
One problem with icloud is that if you send files more that 10-15 MBs from another mail service provide.icloud server will not receive the mail instead it will reject and deliver a postmaster intimation at the source mail

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the email service of the RECIPIENT of your email is presenting the size limit problem.  Your ability to send an attachment to someone is limited to the SMALLER of the limits imposed by the sender's server and the receiver's server.

iCloud caps attachments to 20 Megabytes:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4863

10 Megabytes is the general rule of thumb for email attachments  (However, you should leave room for encoding overhead).  If your file is close to this, try zipping the file, or using a service like fileChute, DropBox, or good old fashioned sneakerNet. :)